# Break out of an overflow:auto Container

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a div-container inside an overflow:auto container, but I want this container to break out of the overflow:auto conatiner. I need this for a date-picker which should overlay the border of a scrollable container and should not be cut by this. Currently I have to scroll if I want to see the last row of the calendar for example. This isn´t a good solution.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Content</p>
  <div class="breakout_anchor">
    <p>Anchor</p>
    <div class="breakout_element">
      <h1>I want to break out of the wrapper!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[Here is a simple plunker to show my problem.](http://plnkr.co/edit/KvwDowulGm17O3goF4SC?p=preview)

Is it possible to solve this problem without javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using position:fixed on the breakout_element and then positioning it in the correct spot.

```
.breakout_anchor:hover .breakout_element {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 130px;
    left: 90px;
}
```

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tzes2Bu6NzEZbSZR2uvp?p=preview

Comment: Looks like a good way, but this solution only works correctly if the container wasn´t scrolled before :-(

Comment: Yes sorry about that. Why dont you just use the browser date picker with an input type=date. See updated plunker... this will work in any scroll position, hover over anchor then click the down arrow to have full calendar. http://plnkr.co/edit/Tzes2Bu6NzEZbSZR2uvp?p=preview

Comment: My datepicker has to work in different timezones, we also need a momentjs-object as result.

Comment: Solved my problem by changing from Absolute to Fixed.